# How to protect home from the main connection line short circuit?

Tags: transformer, safety, protection, short-circuit, home-installation

I am living in a village and we often face issues with main connection input neutral getting shorted and having good amount of current/voltage.

The transformer often gets issues, disrupting supply and neutral shorted.

I have a `MCB` and `Earth` setup, but its of no use if supply line itself is compromised.

I am not sure what more I could add, but in simple terms Live and Neutral both are partially shorted from supply line/transformer due to some fault.

I am search for a device which can be installed in home to protect against such cases.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you explain better?

Comment: What country are you in, and what kinds of problems is the voltage on the neutral wire causing?

Comment: I am from a remote village in India, Electronic and sensitive equipment fails due to this leak of current in neutral.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that your problems are caused by a break in the neutral wire that results in a 'floating neutral'.

Under this condition, consumers would experience either over-voltage or under-voltage depending on the imbalance caused by the broken neutral.

The worst case scenario would be a simultaneous 'floating neutral' and 'line to floating neutral' fault.

[image]

Under this condition two sets of consumers would be supplied 415 V instead of 240 V and the rest would have no power.

The solution would be a 'multi-grounded neutral' system.

In this system, the neutral conductor would be connected to earth at the distribution transformer, at each consumer and at specified poles.

[image]

With that, the 'floating neutral' condition would be avoided and the 'worst case scenario' mentioned above would cause a breaker to trip to clear the fault.

The onus is on the utility service provider to give a solution.

There is no possibility of a solution at the consumer.

Comment: This is exactly the problem. Does having earth 5kva load capacity as neutral in would be helpful as the floating neutral current would not be used?

Comment: Hi Milind, You cannot solve the problem by earthing the neutral at your end alone (it's also not permitted). You need to approach your state electricity board for a solution involving all consumers.

Answer (score 0):

Things one can try to fix an often breaking utility power:

1. Apply political and/or judicial pressure over the utility provider to fix their grid - slow and maybe hard, but efficient in terms of effort vs outcome.

If the utility provider is forced to pay for the broken equipment, they will maintain their stuff better.

2. Use overvoltage protecting devices.

For the usual home/office appliances, the overvoltage protectors exist in the form of protected extension cords.

For a more general protection of a whole building or a powerful industrial equipment, there are bigger devices that could be installed in or near the breaker/meter panel.

3. Like p.2, but more extensive: use an UPS device.

Be aware that they quickly get expensive with added power and/or protective functions. On the other hand, expensive equipment and/or operation can justify the investment. This is how server rooms are powered even in places with more or less reliable power grid.

4. Run your own power plant.

Depending on your needs, your budget and what your utility provider can and cannot do, an own generator or a solar/wind/battery setup may be a viable option, too.